# JavaScript; Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

```js
(function IIFE() {
    'use strict';
    
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i <= l; i += 1) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            
            for (let i = 0; i <= l; i += 1) {
                
                buttons[i].className = '';
                
                this.className = 'active';
            }
            
        };
    }
    
    
    
    // just for testing purpose
    for (var k = 0; k <= 10; k +=1){
        alert(k);
    }
      
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test UI</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><button class="active">A</button></li>
        <li><button>B</button></li>
        <li><button>C</button></li>
    </ul>
                                 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I was wondering why the alert() is not doing job.
I didn´t know that there was a failure before, because it was working like expected.

Now I am wondering why is buttons[i] undefined?

The code is written in ES6.

Thanks for your help

Comment: it should be `i < l` rather than `i <= l`

Comment: Oh, yes that´s it. Thank you much!

Comment: And you should write `i++` instead of `i += 1`, way prettier :D

Comment: I agree that it is prettier, but I think I remember to have read some articel (also one of Douglas Crockford) why we should prefer +=1 instead of ++. I´m not sure with the reason to explain, but I will check, thanks for advising :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I am wondering why is buttons[i] undefined?

Because your condition is `i <= l` and when `i` becomes `l`, then `buttons[i]` becomes `undefined` - **remember that index begins at 0**.

**Demo**

```js
(function IIFE() {
    'use strict';
    
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                
                buttons[i].className = '';                    
                this.className = 'active';
            }                
        };
    }
    // just for testing purpose
    for (var k = 0; k <= 10; k +=1){
        alert(k);
    }
      
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test UI</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><button class="active">A</button></li>
        <li><button>B</button></li>
        <li><button>C</button></li>
    </ul>
                                 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```